# svn: merge trunk with files that have no version control history

Tags: svn, merge, branch

I am working on a version control-wise not terribly well-organized project. I have my own version of our program under version control (svn); my boss, however, does not use version control, thus there is no shared repository. He made several changes to his version of the program, and now he asked me to incorporate those changes into my version - doing it manually would be extremely cumbersome, so I thought perhaps I could save all his files as a branch of my work and let svn do the merging (I have never merged anything before, I don't actually know much about svn I'm afraid...). The trouble is that all svn seems to have done is copying the files my boss added to his version, but no changes seem to have been made to my copies of the source code files which he had changed in his version of the program.

Well, here's what I did (following an online tutorial):

1. I checked out a new working copy of my trunk and one of the newly created branch (that contains the files which I had just copied from my boss' directory). I thought perhaps this would be safer than just working with the working copy that I normally use, as I didn't really know what I was doing...
2. I `cd`'ed into my newly created `trunk` working copy; there I entered

`svn merge file:///home/user/svn/repository/branches/the_new_branch`

I got this output:

```
--- Merging r8 through r27 into '.': 
   C macro/forall.mcr
A    macro/upscale.mcr
   C macro/sbond.mcr
...
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 429
```

Now I would like to know if/how I can get a summary of what exact changes have been performed (e.g. what lines of source code - if any - have been changed), and in case only files were added that had not been there before, how I can get svn to also examine the files' contents and perform merges on that level as well.

In case anyone on here could help me out that would be great, so thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT: I'm using Linux.

Answer (score 1):

in retrospect: If using Windows, a manual merge using WinMerge may be your best bet.

Next Time:

- check out a local copy, call it 'Boss'
- export from 'Boss' and give him that source
- keep working on your own checked out copy
- when the bosses changes are done, copy them over the Boss
- update 'Boss'
- checkin 'Boss'

And you're done.

Answer (score 0):

I would do as if your boss had made a feature-branch, and then merge this feature branch to your trunk :

Try to find from which revision of you trunk your boss started making changes (lets' say it's revision 1000).

Then create a branch from this revision, and switch your working copy to that branch.

Now replace the files in this working copy by the files in your boss's project. You could use WinMerge or an equivalent program to compere the directories recursively and find which files are new, modified, deleted or unchanged.

Commit the changes to the branch.

Then, merge the changes from trunk to branch, starting at 1000, to HEAD. This is where you'll have to resolve conflicts. Once it's done, the feature branch contains all your boss's changes and is up to date with the trunk.

Now you can reintegrate the feature branch into the trunk, and threaten your boss to kill him if he continues not using revision control.